# Always the same deposit address for a user?

Tags: api, blockchain.info, payment, payment-processors

I'm wondering if it is possible to at creation of a user account also save a deposit address(blockchain.info receive payments API) which the user will always use when he/she wants to deposit coins.

Ofcourse I know it's possible to save the deposit address with the user but will it work to always have the users always deposit to a specific address?

will it cause any problems like take the total received balance of the address all the time when the user deposits? eg: balance = balance + (total received coins + just deposited coins)

Tried to explain my concerns and questions to the best of my ability hopefully I can get some answers because google doesn't have any in this case.

Comment: I can't tell, is this a question about Bitcoin in general, or about the features available from a Blockchain.info wallet?

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to use an address more than once? It is.

Comment: I'm refering to the blockchain.info receive api

Comment: In general the rule is: do NOT reuse addresses. Addresses are for one time use only! There are good reasons for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bc.info receive paments API will NOT work if you reuse addresses. The funds will still be yours since the addresses are hierarchical deterministic, but the callback notification will not fire. Your site will not know when a new deposit has been made unless you check manually. I suppose you could create a "refresh my balance" button for your users, but you'd need to put some restrictions on how often they can click so you don't exceed API request limits.